# React Native App not running successfully by running the command 'npx react-native run-android' , but runs successfuly when run through android studio

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio

I have a react native app which was developed 2 years ago. Now when I run it using the command npx react-native run-android or yarn android. It says:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: spawn EPERM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:405:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:677:9)
    at Object.spawnWithSignal [as spawn] (child_process.js:911:17)
    at module.exports (/Users/huzaifafarooqi/AndroidStudioProjects/shoplay-mobile-main/node_modules/execa/index.js:205:26)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/huzaifafarooqi/AndroidStudioProjects/shoplay-mobile-main/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:106:32)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/huzaifafarooqi/AndroidStudioProjects/shoplay-mobile-main/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:149:41)
    at /Users/huzaifafarooqi/AndroidStudioProjects/shoplay-mobile-main/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:132:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/huzaifafarooqi/AndroidStudioProjects/shoplay-mobile-main/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

But when I open the android folder and run it in the android studio, with the Java version 11, it launches the app successfully , but the launched app shows the error that

```
Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
```

Considering that I have ran the server using command 'npx react-native start' but the server is just running it is not showing any requests received. Also I have run this command  `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` but still no results.

Now I want to run this app using the react native so that I could edit it further using the hot reload feature. As the app is building successfully on android studio , so it shows that there are no build errors in the code. But it is not running using the npx command in react native. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this by running the command `adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in the terminal and then running the project on the device from android studio. Referenced from : https://reactnative-archive-august-2023.netlify.app/docs/0.65/running-on-device